# Is there a way to force EF Core to ignore SQL datatypes

Tags: sql, vb.net, orm, entity-framework-core

How can I force EF Core to handle multiple sql data types for a single property? The goal is to handle multiple client databases that handle the same types of things but are not uniform.

Take the following, this only seems to work if the client database has decimal compatible data type.

```
    Public Property PieceThickness As Decimal
    Get
        PieceThickness = _pieceThickness
    End Get
    Set(value As Decimal)
        _pieceThickness = value
    End Set
End Property
```

But some clients will have a PieceThickness as varchar(9). Thus throwing an error, even if I manually map the column.

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of MailPiece)().Property(Function(t) t.PieceThickness).
         HasColumnName("Thickness").HasColumnType("varchar(9)")
```

"An exception occured while reading a database value for property 'MailPiece.PieceThickness'. The expected type was 'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]' but the actual value was of type 'System.String'."

I could obviously have another string property for PieceThickness, but want to avoid this if possible. Making the property an Object doesn't work either.

I understand the model needs to match the database exactly, but I'm hoping there is a work around.

EDIT: I think this best bet to handle this situation is to use a factory pattern or a provider factory: http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns

Doing this I'll have a scale able solution that can diverge from the norm on a client by client basis.

Comment: This issue when resolved would help solve this. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/242

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I can think of is converting whatever you read from the database into a Decimal or other numeric type and hope the data there was valid. For instance, you can use a view and read from that and it will be defined with part of it as

```
SELECT CAST(PieceThickness AS numeric(18,0)) PieceThickness FROM YourTable
```

amongst other fields. Then run you LINQ query off the view instead of the table. You can then pick for your field a type that can be found in various database systems.

**Update**

Seeing as you may want to perform crud operations, I might suggest another workaround that is not quite as elegant. I have a database that I work with that I cannot create sprocs and/or views on. It has some dates in Unix Timestamp format but I need to use the actual dates in my code. The workaround I use is like this...

```
Public Class Demo
    Public Property GpsTime As Integer

    Public Readonly Property AssembledTime As Date
        Get
            Return GpsTime.FromUnixTimestamp()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

where FromUnixTimestamp() is an extension method I have to translate that. If you really cannot find a common type other than varchar, you can store it in the database as a varchar and work with it using a method like this that can write back to the string property before saving. You just ensure that EF Core ignores the Decimal property.

In your case, you will need code such as the following:

```
Public Property PieceThickness As String

Public Property PieceThicknessD As Decimal
    Get
        Dim workingValue As Decimal
        If Decimal.TryParse(PieceThickness, workingValue) Then Return workingValue
    End Get
    Set(value as Decimal)
        PieceThickness = value.ToString()
    End Set
End Property
```

So that's the workaround I was thinking of. Although I still think you should be able to get a datatype common to the various database systems.

Comment: Does mapping to a view allow for normal CRUD operations?

Comment: That workaround was for reading the data. I have not used an ORM solution with an updatable view so I cannot answer that one accurately. You can do your crud with a stored procedure if you like. Or rather, use datatype other than decimal that you know all your target platforms can handle

Comment: I have updated my answer, @DavidTheDev check if it works for you now

Comment: Help me understand this, using the above logic I would need to have the target database have a uniform thinkness datatype of varchar and then call Conver.ToDecimal.

Comment: In a way yes. The field would be stored as nvarchar seeing as you are open to that. You object at runtime would then use a property you have to deal with the actual data. When saving, you can then set the string property. It is rough, but if you cannot find a common data type, that should work. 

I'm updating my answer with something more suited to your situation

Comment: I didn't technically mention this, but I need to be able to use this in other dbs and there the Thickness will be numeric.

Comment: Which DBs are you targeting. Perhaps I can help you find a suitable numeric datatype that is common to all of them.

Comment: To many to list, this problem will extend beyond just Thickness. There are many other columns with many different types.

Comment: I think your solution is viable, but was hoping for a more elegant approach so I could avoid having additional properties to handle different data types.

Comment: Are you using database first, or code first? Why I ask is you may want to consider using Double instead of Decimal. All DBMSs I know have something that works with double, that way, you can let EF figure out how to translate the data from DB to runtime object. Have a look at this link https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp for more info. You also want to look into the provider pattern to design your DAL in such a way that you can swap it out based on which platform you're targeting while the bulk of the code stays the same

Comment: Code first. Will have to look at the pattern to see if it fits my needs. Certainly sounds like a good suggestion in terms of making something look nice.